# Programming a distributed application written in C#, Ruby and Java using XML-RPC

Tags: c#, java, ruby, xml-rpc, distributed-system

I am tasked with writing a distributed event managing tool where each client, either a Ruby, C# or Java Client, synchronises all changes with a list of registered clients. I have to use `XML-RPC` to achieve the goal. My team and I have written up an `XML-RPC` client and server in each language and will provide the relevant source code below. If you require more code, please let me know.

The problem is that I can get Java and C# to communicate with each other. Ruby can communicate with the others but C# (and maybe Java, haven't tested yet) have problems addressing the Ruby server. I guess the problem is with the Endpoint. First let me give you some code. When reading please be aware that the code is actually written by a team and naming conventions differ a bit:

**C# client**

```
Uri _address = new Uri("http://" + _s + ":8000/xmlrpc/EventManagerService");
ChannelFactory<IEventManagerWCF_XML_RPC> _factory = new ChannelFactory<IEventManagerWCF_XML_RPC>(new WebHttpBinding(WebHttpSecurityMode.None), new EndpointAddress(_address));
_factory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new XmlRpcEndpointBehavior());
IEventManagerWCF_XML_RPC _proxy = _factory.CreateChannel();
```

`_proxy` will not hold the client for a given URI. Those are stored in a dictionary and used when the need arises to synchronise events. One such synchronisation would happen in the case of a modification;

```
 foreach(IEventManagerWCF_XML_RPC proxy in this.peers.Values)
        proxy.modify(_id, _field, _newValue);
```

Here is an extract from the IEventManagerWCF_XML_RPC interface;

```
 [OperationContract(Action = "EventManagerService.modify")]
 bool modify(int id, string field, string newValue);
```

**C# XML RPC service**

```
 Uri _baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8000/xmlrpc");
 _eventManagerHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(EventManagerService), _baseAddress);
     try
     {
     ServiceEndpoint epXmlRpc = _eventManagerHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IEventManagerWCF_XML_RPC), new WebHttpBinding(WebHttpSecurityMode.None), "EventManagerService");
     epXmlRpc.Behaviors.Add(new XmlRpcEndpointBehavior());

     ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
     smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
     _eventManagerHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
     _eventManagerHost.Open();
     }
     catch (CommunicationException ce)
     {
     Console.WriteLine("An exception occurred: {0}", ce.Message);
     _eventManagerHost.Abort();
     }
```

Nothing special here I guess. Lets move on to the Java code!

**Java Client**

```
XmlRpcClientConfigImpl config = new XmlRpcClientConfigImpl();
try {
  config.setServerURL(new URL("http://"+ip+":8000/xmlrpc/EventManagerService"));

} 
catch (MalformedURLException e) {  
  e.printStackTrace();
}

config.setEnabledForExtensions(true);  
config.setConnectionTimeout(60 * 1000);
config.setReplyTimeout(60 * 1000);      
XmlRpcClient client = new XmlRpcClient();
client.setTransportFactory(new XmlRpcCommonsTransportFactory(client));
client.setConfig(config);
xmlRpcPeers.put(ip, client);
```

`xmlRpcPeers` now holds the different clients. They are called as follows;

```
for(XmlRpcClient peer : this.xmlRpcPeers.values())
  {
   try {
    peer.execute("EventManagerService.modify", params);
   } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
  }
```

The **Java Server** has it's own class and is instantiated with a simple `new` call;

```
public class Server extends Thread{

/**
* Server port
*/
  private static final int port = 8000;

  /**
   * Starts the XML-RPC server
   */
  public void run(){
   WebServer webServer = new WebServer(port);        
   XmlRpcServer xmlRpcServer = webServer.getXmlRpcServer();   

   PropertyHandlerMapping phm = new PropertyHandlerMapping();
   try
   {
    phm.addHandler("EventManagerService", lu.uni.binfo.ds.EventManager_Java.EventManagerService.class);
   } 
   catch (XmlRpcException e1) 
   {
    e1.printStackTrace();
   }           
      xmlRpcServer.setHandlerMapping(phm);        
      XmlRpcServerConfigImpl serverConfig = (XmlRpcServerConfigImpl) xmlRpcServer.getConfig();
      serverConfig.setEnabledForExtensions(true);
      serverConfig.setContentLengthOptional(false);          
      try 
      {
        webServer.start();
      } 
      catch (IOException e) 
      {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

Up till now everything seemed to work fine. Adding Ruby to the mix is what gives the most trouble. Here is the relevant code;

**Ruby Client**
Ruby clients are also stored in a dictionary. It is populated as follows;

```
@devices_XMLRPC[key] = EventManagerClient_XMLRPC.new(tokens[0]).device
```

The code for the class is:

```
class EventManagerClient_XMLRPC
  @uri
  @device
  attr_accessor :uri, :device

  def initialize(uri)
    @uri = uri
    @device = XMLRPC::Client.new2(
            uri="http://" << @uri.to_s << ":8000/xmlrpc/EventManagerService", proxy=nil, timeout=30)
  end
end
```

A call to synchronise on modifications looks like this:

```
@devices_XMLRPC.each_value { |client| client.call("EventManagerService.modify", tokens[0], field, value) }
```

**Ruby Server**

```
server = XMLRPC::Server.new(8000, "127.0.0.1")
server.add_handler("xmlrpc/EventManagerService", EventManagerService.instance)
puts "Server ready!"
server.serve
```

The EventManagerService class:

```
class EventManagerService
  include Singleton
  @manager

  def initialize()
    @manager = EventManager.instance
  end

  def modify(id, field, newValue)
      puts "modify called"
      @manager.modify([id, field, newValue], 1)
  end

end
```

`EventManager` being the class where all the logic resides.

The error when trying to communicate from C# to Ruby is an `EndPointNotFoundException` that reads:

`There was no endpoint listening at http://ip:8000/xmlrpc/EventManagerService that could accept the message.[...]`

I tried fiddling around with the endpoint declaration but cannot seem to get it to work. The Ruby documentation does not help either. I am in need of help!

Answer (score 0):

You could try inspecting the traffic that goes over the line with [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/). With this tool, you would be able to see the actual HTTP data that is transferred between the different applications. Maybe this provides a hint as to why you have problems communicating between Ruby and C#.